# Almofire in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm about to start a new project using Swift 3. My project is not so complicated. Subscriptions and In-App purchases with user profile data using our APIs server. Is Almofire support enough on Swift 3?

Comment: AF is built on top of swift and the libraries that come with it, so strictly speaking, no, but in a way also yes. that you ask this question indicates you're quite confused about what swift / AF is...

Comment: well, now I'm confused :)....I know what AF is and what Swift is. But just wondering if it is the best choice when writing Swift 3. or maybe using NSURLSession.

Comment: best depends on you and your situation, it's a personal / team preference

Comment: Tried Alamofire with Xcode 8 Beta 1. Lots of issues with Swift 2 to 3 conversion, but then again, Swift 3 is still in beta. Wait a nit for the Alamofire team to update their packages for the new Swift version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alamofire now provides a Swift 3 branch. If you use Cocoapods you can point to the branch like this

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift3'
```

Reference:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1316